# Why is this ng-grid pagination working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-watch

Here is what I understand by the if condition in the following code:

```
$scope.pagingOptions = {
    pageSizes: [250, 500, 1000],
    pageSize: 250,
    currentPage: 1
};

$scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
          $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
}, true);
```

whenever the `pagingOptions` changes **and**  the `currentPage` property has changed the `if` conditions becomes true, so the `getPagedDataAsync` method gets executed.

But even if I don't change the `currentPage` but the `pageSize` from the UI, the grid gets refreshed.
Which I don't expect to happen(according to my understanding). So why is that grid getting refreshed?

From here, I have taken the code:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/
with the **Server-Side Paging Example** heading

Comment: You haven't asked any actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The `true` at the end of the `$watch` indicates a *deep* watch of the scope object `pagingOptions`.

So, if `true` is passed in as on optional third parameter, Angular will do a deep equality check.  Therefore, the `pageSize` property will be checked for equality and will be different.

Documentation for `$watch` and the third parameter `[objectEquality]` is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Comment: in that case what would be the use of `if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage)`, we can directly call the the `getPagedDataAsync ` method.

Comment: Yes, I think that the `newVal !== oldVal` is redundant in this case. Or maybe both conditions... :)

Answer (score 0):

The provided code seems to contain unnecessary complexity. When doing an ["object equality watch"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) (by setting the third argument of `$watch` to `true`), object's property values are compared instead of object reference. If we suppose that `pageSizes` property value never changes, the watch informs us properly and only about changes to `pageSize` and `currentPage` values. So the only code needed inside is the call to page refresh:

```
$scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function () {
      $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more watch

```
$scope.$watch('pagingOptions.pageSize', function (newVal, oldVal) {
 if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
      $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
}, true);
```